# Install a CKeditor plugin to Liferay 7

Tags: ckeditor, liferay

I would like to extend my Liferay 7 with a CKEditor plugin. I found [this guide](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/adding-new-behavior-to-an-editor) but I can't go over step 3 because I can't find any package/artifact containing the required *DynamicInclude* class.

Note: I am not using Blade, I am using Maven so I need the correct dependency.

Note 2: The plugin I would like to add is [base64image](http://ckeditor.com/addon/base64image).

Answer (score 0):

Looking on the [Github repo](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/servlet/taglib/DynamicInclude.java), it looks like DynamicInclude is part of Portal Kernel. You should be able to include it with that artifact I believe: https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22com.liferay.portal.kernel%22